# Adding custom attribute to customer object for event observer

Tags: attributes, customer, event-observer, register

I'm sending some user data to backoffice upon new user registration. The problem I am facing is that i need to send some custom attributes (like whether or not certain option was selected) along the normal data (name, date of birth etc.).

Now the problem I am having is that when user registers I try to send date to backoffice in `customerRegisterSuccess` and `customerSaveAfter` events. But neither one of them has my custom attributes, only standard ones. (Checking using`$observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getData()`).

Is there any way to add my custom attributes to said customer object so they are retrievable  in event observers without loading entire customer model?